# FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'example.pdf' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30))

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, package

I am trying to create a pdf generator using flutter and the pdf package, as I just started I have imported the package and copy pasted the code for trial's sake as in the youtube tutorial, it worked in the tutorial but it's showing this FileSystemException for me.

kindly, help me guys out guys.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

Future<void> main() async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
        child: pw.Text('Hello World!'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  final file = File('example.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to storage before filename and extension. To get /storage/emulated/0/downloads, you can used a Third-party package [external_path](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path). Below code will return your desired Directory path

```
var path = await .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
final file = File('${path}/example.pdf')
```